# How can I find references to symbols in a project?

Tags: project, etags

I've generated a TAGS file, which holds all my symbols.

I'm not sure I understand how xref-find-references is supposed to work, but I only get results on symbols that exists in the current buffer.

Is that how it's supposed to work? I really want results for the entire project.

I found this command:

```
M-x tags-search
```

, but it's cumbersome to use, as I have to hit

```
M-x file-loop-continue
```

.. everytime it gets a hit. It's not like a get a list view.

Comment: xref-find-references should show results for the whole project, but it all depends on what Xref backend is active. Perhaps you have a package installed that makes it use something local to the current file.